# How to Compare Averages of Categories

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 3 tables:
table1:

```
Category  
--------  
1  
2  
3  
4
```

table2:

```
Branch | Category  
------------------  
A1     |   1  
A2     |   1  
A3     |   2  
A4     |   3  
A5     |   4  
A6     |   4  
A7     |   4
```

table3: Values

```
Date     | Branch  | Value
---------------------------
1/1/2019 |  A1     |   35  
1/1/2019 |  A2     |   40  
1/1/2019 |  A4     |   62  
1/1/2019 |  A5     |   10  
1/1/2019 |  A6     |   20  
1/1/2019 |  A7     |   35
```

Table Connections are:
Category -->--- Branch
and 
Branch -->-- Values

I am trying to compare the value of every Branch with the average of the Category that belongs to. If the value of the Branch is below Category's average then it is good else is bad.

If I create a matrix with Branch, value and Category Average
it looks like this :

```
Branch  |   Value  |   Category Average
-------------------------------------
  A1    |    35    |   35  
  A2    |    40    |   40  
  A4    |    62    |   62  
  A5    |    10    |   10  
  A6    |    20    |   20  
  A7    |    35    |   35  



BranchAVG = AVERAGE(Table3[Value])
CategoryAVG = AVERAGEX(VALUES(Categories[Category]);[BranchAVG])
```

But it should look like this:

```
Branch  |   Value  |   Category Average | Good/Bad
------------------------------------------------
  A1    |    35    |       37.5         |  Good             
  A2    |    40    |       37.5         |  Bad  
  A4    |    62    |       62.0         |  Good  
  A5    |    10    |       21.7         |  Good  
  A6    |    20    |       21.7         |  Good  
  A7    |    35    |       21.7         |  Bad
```

Is there any possible way to do that?
Thanks in advance
Elias

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a Category column to your Value table:

```
Category = RELATED(Branch[Category])
```

And after this add the AgeragePerCategory column:

```
AgeravePerCategory = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Values'[Value]);FILTER('Values'; 'Values'[Category] = EARLIER('Values'[Category])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.
To work it out I had to add an additional filter to Date, because it averages all values regardless the date.
So the AveragePerCategory it looks like:

```
AveragePerCategory = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Values'[Value]);FILTER('Values'; 'Values'[Category] = EARLIER('Values'[Category]) && 'Values'[Date] = EARLIER('Values'[Date])))
```